# Numbers do not appear in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I am writing a report and the brackets in my bibliography remain empty, also the citations in text are question marks. How do I get numbers in them?

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,10pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{minitoc} 
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[square,sort,compress,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{notes}
\usepackage{watermark}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{sectsty,textcase}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
Some text \cite{carmeliet2000}. 
Extra text \cite{alberts2002}. 

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{allsources}
```

It shows the references in the bibliography, but does not put numbers in the brackets, in the bibliography as well as in the text.

allsources.bib looks like:

```
@ARTICLE {carmeliet2000,
author  = "Peter Carmeliet and Rakesh K. Jain",
title   = "Angiogenesis in cancer and other diseases",
journal = "Nature",
year    = "2000",
volume  = "407",
pages   = "249-257",
month   = "sep",
DOI     = "doi:10.1038/35025220"
}

@BOOK {alberts2002,
author    = "Alberts B. and Johnson A. and Lewis J. et al",
title     = "\textit{Blood Vessels and Endothelial Cells} in Molecular 
Biology of the Cell",
publisher = "New York: Garland Science",
year      = "2002",
edition   = "fourth"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Tex.Se. The numbers are displaying,  I have executed the same file. All you need to do this is that, run twice the source file.

Comment: I did run it several times now, but still no numbers

Comment: Clean the auxiliary files once, then run the source file twice.

Comment: Off-topic: The `author field of the second entry should be `"Alberts, B. and Johnson, A. and Lewis, J. and others",`. Note the insertion of three commas between surnames and initials and the replacement of "et al" with "and others".

Answer (score 2):

Just check the attached image. If you are using tex studio, go to Tools -> clean auxiliary files, then run the file twice.

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to provide the instruction that BibTeX needs to be run... (Not running BibTeX is what appears to be the OP's problem.)

Comment: As suggested by Mico, you need to run bibtex too soon after compiling your source file.

Comment: I have done all that. I use Texmaker and my quick build is PdfLatex Bibtex PdfLatex (2x) Show Pdf.  It shows the references in the bibliography, but just not the numbers between the square brackets.